# Changing out rng as input to DH keying material

Tags: rust

I am currently creating some DH keys using the [x25519-dalek-ng](https://crates.io/crates/x25519-dalek-ng) crate for it.

Using `rand_core` I can create them like this, with the OSrng:

```
use x25519_dalek_ng::{self,PublicKey, StaticSecret};
use rand_core::{OsRng};
fn main() {
        let i_dh_privkey : StaticSecret  = StaticSecret::new(OsRng);
        let i_dh_public_key = PublicKey::from(&i_dh_privkey);
}
```

But I want to change to a different rng, one that does not require a OS.
So I wanted to shift to [rand_chacha](https://crates.io/crates/rand_chacha).
I then tried doing this:

```
use x25519_dalek_ng::{self,PublicKey, StaticSecret};
use rand_chacha::{ChaCha8Rng};
fn main() {
        let i_dh_privkey : StaticSecret  = StaticSecret::new(ChaCha8Rng);
        let i_dh_public_key = PublicKey::from(&i_dh_privkey);
}
```

And rust doesnt like this, and says:

```
help: use struct literal syntax instead'
```

Which I don't really udnerstand, both OSrng and ChaCha8Rng are structs.

`StaticSecret::new()` takes anything that implements crpytorng, should I do something to implement that for the chacha rng?

Comment: Can you include the full error including the code location information?

Comment: BTW, I noticed that [rand_chacha seems to depend on rand_core](https://crates.io/crates/rand_chacha/0.3.1/dependencies)

Comment: I think the issue is that an OsRng is an empty struct with no members, while a ChaCha8Rng *does* have members and so needs to be constructed. It seems to implement a from_feed from the [SeedableRng](https://docs.rs/rand_core/latest/rand_core/trait.SeedableRng.html) trait that I think you probably want to use.